# How many upvotes and downvotes have been cast since site launch?

Tags: discussion, voting, statistics

I apologize if this is off-topic; if it is, I'll delete it right away.

I'm actually curious how many upvotes and how many downvotes have been cast since Stack Overflow was started.  There doesn't seem to be some tracker on the main site nor anywhere else, but I find it interesting to see how many upvotes and downvotes (and possibly flags) there have been since site launch.

Basically, how many upvotes and downvotes have been cast since the first SE, Stack Overflow, started? I'm not asking just for one site, I'm curious about all of Stack Exchange as a whole.

Comment: http://data.stackexchange.com/

Comment: According to this: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Votes WHERE VoteTypeId IN (2, 3)` there have been 52410987 up and down votes on StackOverflow. You'll have to run the same query multiple times and add them up for all sites though.

Answer (score 4):

The Stack Exchange Data Explorer hold the votes (up and down) on non-deleted posts. So it is not possible to find all votes ever cast but the numbers here are mind blowing enough.

Use [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/733051) when SEDE has updated on Sunday, 03:00 UTC to get the update voting statistics.

When run today the result is:

[image: SEDE up downvote stat network wide]

Which shows that network-wide, just shy of 160 million votes have been cast (the vast majority being upvotes).

Comment: *"the vast majority being upvotes"* - That's quite implicit due to "Data Explorer hold the votes [..] on non-deleted posts".

Comment: @Tom That and the other mechanics: the higher rep threshold to cast downvotes, the rep loss for downvoting answers on a gamified site  which incentivizes maximizing reputation, and attracts people who are respond to such incentives, and the general atmosphere of people interpreting downvotes as cruel or punitive. There is no surprise the vast majority of votes is upvotes.

Comment: Let’s see: 213,011 total downvotes on EL&U, and [my user stats on that site](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/55623/dan-bron?tab=topactivity) say I’ve cast 5,882 of them. That means I’ve personally cast ~3% of all downvotes in the history of EL&U. Where’s my grumpy curmudgeon badge?

Comment: @DanBron Sorry to crash the party, but 213k are just the "still visible" downvotes. Most of the downvoted stuff gets deleted and these posts don't count here anymore. Thus your percentage should be lower.

Comment: @Tom I saw your first comment on that topic, and responded to it ;)

Comment: @DanBron Oh ... missed that ^^. Sorry.